# In Autohotkey Format the output of a ListBox?

Tags: autohotkey

In Autohotkey, I have the following code :

```
^r::
Gui, Add, ListBox, Multi vMyListBox r10, Strawberries|Pears|Oranges|`r|Beans|Peas|Tomatoes|Turnips|
Gui, Add, Button, Default, OK
Gui, Show
return

ButtonOK:
    Gui, Submit
    MsgBox % MyListBox
    send, % MyListBox
return
```

The output is, e.g. :

```
Strawberries|Beans|Turnips
```

But I would like it to be :

```
Strawberries, Beans, Turnips,
```

How should I proceed ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [RegEx](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm).

Using [RegExReplace()](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExReplace.htm) with the MyListBox variable as the haystack and "\|" as the needle. See [this interactive](https://regexr.com/5rnvr) for an explanation of this particular RegEx needle.

Saving the replaced version of the String in a variable called `NewStr` gives us this line of code:

`NewStr := RegExReplace(MyListBox, "\|" , Replacement := ", ")`

Current Code:

```
^r::
Gui, Add, ListBox, Multi vMyListBox r10, Strawberries|Pears|Oranges|`r|Beans|Peas|Tomatoes|Turnips|
Gui, Add, Button, Default, OK
Gui, Show
return

ButtonOK:
    Gui, Submit
    MsgBox % MyListBox
    NewStr := RegExReplace(MyListBox, "\|" , Replacement := ", ")
    MsgBox % NewStr
    send, % NewStr
return
```

---

However, this version does not add a trailing ", ". In order to add this, let's just append a ", " to the NewStr variable we just created with `NewStr.=", "`

---

## Final Code:

```
^r::
Gui, Add, ListBox, Multi vMyListBox r10, Strawberries|Pears|Oranges|`r|Beans|Peas|Tomatoes|Turnips|
Gui, Add, Button, Default, OK
Gui, Show
return

ButtonOK:
    Gui, Submit
    MsgBox % MyListBox
    NewStr := RegExReplace(MyListBox, "\|" , Replacement := ", ")
    NewStr.=", "
    MsgBox % NewStr
    send, % NewStr
return
```

Comment: Thank you very very much ; exactly what I was hoping for !

Comment: If this solution solves your question, could you please mark it as the accepted answer so that others know this question is resolved?

Comment: I don't see any reason to RegexReplace here, just do a normal [StrReplace](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StrReplace.htm).

Comment: My bad, I didn't know that StrReplace was a function that existed. It looks like the Regex line could have been replaced with the more intuitive `NewStr := StrReplace(MyListBox, "|", ", ")`. Thank you for bringing this up @0x464e.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot. I hope everything is OK now.